# populate columns based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Hoping someone can help me write an SQL script or function.

I have a data source which i want the function to go through and populate the relevant columns based on the 2 specified columns.

So the name and value columns.

E.g.

```
name= A+b+c+d 
Value= 2+1+3+5
```

therefore the the script/function should populate column a,b,c,d with values 2,1,3,5 respectively for every row of the data source..

is this possible? if so, can someone show me how.

Comment: Is this an update or an insert?

Comment: @apc it will be an insert.. because the data is in another table currently and I want to take it from that table and insert into another

Comment: please provide some sample data and output to clarify the question.

Comment: what @MT0 offered as the answer (Version 1) is exactly what im after but need the value column to accept anything and not be restricted especially in length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  name  VARCHAR2(7)
        CHECK ( name IS NULL OR REGEXP_LIKE( name, '^[A-D](\+[A-D]){0,3}$', 'i' ),
  value VARCHAR2(200),
  A     VARCHAR2(50),
  B     VARCHAR2(50),
  C     VARCHAR2(50),
  D     VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO your_table ( name, value, a, b, c, d )
  SELECT 'a+b+c+d', 'x2+x1+x3+x5', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a+d+c',   'y7+y3+y4',    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Update Statement**:

```
MERGE INTO your_table dst
USING (
  WITH splitstrings ( rid, name, value, col, val, lvl ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID,
           UPPER( name ),
           value,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( UPPER( name ), '[^+]+', 1, 1 ),
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '[^+]+', 1, 1 ),
           1
    FROM   your_table
    WHERE  name IS NOT NULL
    AND    value IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT rid,
           name,
           value,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( name, '[^+]+', 1, lvl + 1 ),
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '[^+]+', 1, lvl + 1 ),
           lvl + 1
    FROM   splitstrings
    WHERE  lvl < LEAST(
                   REGEXP_COUNT( name, '[^+]+' ),
                   REGEXP_COUNT( value, '[^+]+' )
                 )
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM   ( SELECT rid, col, val FROM splitstrings )
  PIVOT  ( MAX( val ) FOR col IN ( 'A' AS a, 'B' AS b, 'C' AS c, 'D' AS d ) )
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
    SET A = COALESCE( src.A, dst.A ),
        B = COALESCE( src.B, dst.B ),
        C = COALESCE( src.C, dst.C ),
        D = COALESCE( src.D, dst.D );
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table;

NAME    VALUE       A  B  C  D
------- ----------- -- -- -- --
a+b+c+d x2+x1+x3+x5 x2 x1 x3 x5
a+d+c   y7+y3+y4    y7    y4 y3
```

## Version 2:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_source (
  name  VARCHAR2(50),
  value VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO your_source
  SELECT 'a+b+c+d', 'x2+x1+x3+x5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a+d+c',   'y7+y3+y4'    FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE your_destination (
--  name  VARCHAR2(50),
--  value VARCHAR2(50),
  A VARCHAR2(20),
  B VARCHAR2(20),
  C VARCHAR2(20),
  D VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

**Insert Statement**:

```
INSERT INTO your_destination ( /* name, value, */ A, B, C, D )
  WITH splitstrings ( rid, name, value, col, val, lvl ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID,
           UPPER( name ),
           value,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( UPPER( name ), '[^+]+', 1, 1 ),
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '[^+]+', 1, 1 ),
           1
    FROM   your_source
    WHERE  name IS NOT NULL
    AND    value IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT rid,
           name,
           value,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( name, '[^+]+', 1, lvl + 1 ),
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '[^+]+', 1, lvl + 1 ),
           lvl + 1
    FROM   splitstrings
    WHERE  lvl < LEAST(
                   REGEXP_COUNT( name, '[^+]+' ),
                   REGEXP_COUNT( value, '[^+]+' )
                 )
  )
  SELECT /* name, value, */ A,B,C,D
  FROM   ( SELECT rid, /* name, value, */ col, val FROM splitstrings )
  PIVOT  ( MAX( val ) FOR col IN ( 'A' AS a, 'B' AS b, 'C' AS c, 'D' AS d ) );
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM your_destination

A  B  C  D
-- -- -- --
x2 x1 x3 x5
y7    y4 y3
```

Comment: Firstly many thanks for your answer it is extremely helpful, I will be looking into this and ensuring I understand every line. Can i just ask  if i change the 'values' from 2+1+3+5 to 'x2+x1+x3+x5' what do I need to change so the the output shows x2 under A? If i create table with 'x2+x1+x3+x5'  the value column just shows "x2+x1+x", it seems to cut off the rest? How do I rectify this?

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @tony123 Updated

Comment: version 1 was what I am after, just need the value fields to accomodate the x1,x2 etc.. Is it possible to have that but still using version1?
Thanks for all the help so far

Comment: @tony123 Updated again

Comment: thank you so much.. you sir are a legend.. I will be studying to ensure i understand this.. Do you mind If i ask some questions regarding the code to ensure I fully understand? Once again thank you!

Comment: @tony Ask away - but you can hopefully answer most of it yourself by running the individual parts - start with the first select statement up until the  `UNION ALL` then if you understand that then run the entire `WITH` clause (exclude the `PIVOT` line) and finally add in the `PIVOT` line. The `MERGE` statement round it is pretty standard, joining on the `ROWID` pseudo-column to ensure a 1-to-1 correspondence in the self-join.

Comment: @MT0..hey if i want to implement version 2 but want an output like version1 what do i change?

Comment: If I just change the INSERT INTO your_destination ( A, B, C, D ) to include name and value, will that do the trick

Comment: @tony123 Uncomment the commented sections

Comment: perfect that works! I'm trying to understand the whole code in general and have few questions.
1. what is the rid in splitstrings - is this any different from ROWID?
2.I dont understand the code -> WHERE  lvl < LEAST - Can you kindly explain how this is working.
i think i understand most of it now, only pivot function i'm doing further reading on and then hopefully should be there.

Thanks once again

Comment: `rid` is the alias used in the recursive sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause for the `ROWID`. `REGEXP_COUNT` is used to determine the length of the `name` and `value` lists; `LEAST` just takes the lower value of the two list lengths (you should expect both the name and value lists to have equal length but this is just in case they are unequal). The `WHERE lvl < LEAST(...)` clause just stops the query from recursing when the end of the list is reached. `PIVOT` just changes rows into column - grouping the values with the same `ROWID`, `name` and `value` into the same row.

Comment: I'm trying a similar concept where now I'm bringing in 3 columns from source but need the `your_destination` table still populating as earlier. I have added a column into `source` table called ATY and made changes I felt were right but i get an Oracle error of unique constraint violated. The keys are made up of name+value+ATY but im not sure what I'm missing as I included the `ATY` field in the codes. Can you point me in right direction please?

Comment: @tony123 Make a new question with the new set of requirements, include the DDL/DML statements you are using and the query you are trying (and a link back to this question) and I will try to answer there. It is too confusing to keep modifying this question based on changing requirements in comments.

Comment: sure, have made [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204314/populate-column-based-on-other-columns)

Comment: Hi, any chance you can help on my new question. Is the content of the question actually possible? the only difference from this is its 3 columns and looking for a way not to hard code column names

Comment: I have ran into a problem using your solution. For e.g. If I have A+B++E+F, A will have correct value and so will B, but the rest will have incorrect values because of the additional +.. Anyway I can check for additional + and if there is just default that with 999?

Comment: @tony123 How do you know which column the 999 would go into if there is a zero-width string (`NULL`) for the column name?

Comment: I see what you mean. Apologies, I lacked in explaination. Is there a way to skip the any instances of double ++. So for e.g. if I had A+B+C+ it still correctly populates..?