# Populate data based on columns in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

this refers to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177521/populate-columns-based-on-2-columns/44179193?noredirect=1#comment75379695_44179193) I now want to do the same thing but bring in 3 columns from my source table. Name,value and ATY. Based on the values of the source table the correct columns in the destination table should populate. So this would mean, unlike my previous question i don't want to hard code the columns because there maybe situations the table structure changes or I use the same code on different table which the stucture is different.

My source table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE your_source (
  name  VARCHAR2(50),
  value VARCHAR2(50),
  ATY   VARCHAR2(50)
);
INSERT INTO your_source
  SELECT 'a+b+c+d', 'x2+x1+x3+x5','m1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a+d+c',   'y7+y3+y4','m3'    FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE your_destination (
  name  VARCHAR2(50),
  value VARCHAR2(50),
  ATY   VARCHAR2(50),
  A VARCHAR2(20),
  B VARCHAR2(20),
  C VARCHAR2(20),
  D VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

The structure of the destination table may change so maybe more column or fewer columns so can't be hardcoded. Also, the name field from source table maybe more than 4 fields and maybe something like "A+B+C+X+H".. so in this instance only values for A,B,C will be populated as H  & X do not exist, but if there was an instance where H & X did exist they will be populated.
hope this makes sense.

**Output:**

```
SELECT * FROM your_destination

name        value        ATY   A  B  C  D
a+b+c+d   x2+x1+x3+x5     m1   x2 x1 x3 x5            
a+d+c'    y7+y3+y4        m3   y7  0  y4 y3
```

Comment: Investigate Dynamic Sql and PL/SQL

Comment: @RenatoAfonso do you have a link?

Comment: You would need to build up a list of the columns you want to include in the insert/merge and use that in a dynamic query which you run with [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)