# remove extra + from text SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

this refers to a question asked by someone else previously
[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177521/populate-columns-based-on-2-columns)

my question is how do I adapt this solution so that before any function/script is ran the name and value fields are stripped of any additional + and updated so no additional + remain.

For e.g.

```
Name     Value
A+B+C+   1+2+3+
A++B     1++2
```

this should be updated to

```
   Name     Value
    A+B+C   1+2+3
    A+B     1+2
```

once this update has taken place, I can run the solution provided in the previous question.

Thanks

Comment: `replace(columnname, '++', '+')`

Comment: this doesn't remove the last + in the end

Comment: while selecting you can use query like this - SELECT RIGHT('HELLO WORLD', LEN('HELLO WORLD+') - 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `++` with `+` and to remove the `+` at the end of the string.

```
/* sample data */
with input(Name, Value) as (
                            select 'A+B+C+'   ,'1+2+3+' from dual union all
                            select 'A++B'     ,'1++2'   from dual
                            )
/* query */
select trim('+' from regexp_replace(name,  '\+{2,}', '+') ) as name,
       trim('+' from regexp_replace(value, '\+{2,}', '+') ) as value
from input
```

If you need to update a table, you may need:

```
update yourTable
set name = trim('+' from regexp_replace(name, '\+{2,}', '+') ),
    value= trim('+' from regexp_replace(value, '\+{2,}', '+') )
```

In a more compact way, without the external trim ( assuming you have no leading `+`):

```
/* sample data */
with input(Name, Value) as (
                            select 'A+B+C+'      ,'1+2+3+' from dual union all
                            select 'A++B+++C+'   ,'1++2+++3+' from dual union all
                            select 'A+B'         ,'1+2'   from dual
                            )
/* query */
select regexp_replace(name,  '(\+)+(\+|$)', '\2') as name,
       regexp_replace(value, '(\+)+(\+|$)', '\2') as value
from input
```

Comment: how do I do this without hardcoding values and also for 2 columns

Comment: What do you mean with hardcoding? Do you need to handle more than 2 occurrences of `+`? Also, for 2 columns, it will be enough to apply the functions to both columns.

Comment: How can I do this for both my columns called 'name' and 'value'. when I say hard code I mean you manually entered 'A+B+C+'

Comment: This is only an example. I edited to show you how to apply this to a table. To do the same thing for 2 columns, simply apply the functions to both columns.

Comment: ah i see that seems to work.. Now I just need to see how I can update the columns at the same time

Comment: @alexsej - if you use `regexp_replace(NAME, '(\+){2,}', '\1')`, you can cut down on the amount of "hard-coding" the `+`

Comment: @Boneist:you're right, thanks. I was trying to find a single regexp to do both works, without the external TRIM, but still unable...

Comment: @Aleksej yeah, I ran into the same issue too.

Comment: @Boneist: Maybe I've got it, just posted

Comment: @Aleksej haha, I just came up with `regexp_replace(NAME, '\+*((\+)|$)', '\1')` which does the same thing! <insert crying with laughter emoji here> However, it doesn't trim off leading +'s, so I guess if the OP could have those, they'd still have to do at least an ltrim to get rid of them

Comment: Thanks for new update. Can I ask what the difference is between original and new just so I can understand? How comes first solution picks up text that begins with + but second one doesnt?
Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: The TRIM removes the + from both the beginning and the end of the string. Doing the same thing, even handling the multiple occurrences, in a single regupar expression is too much for me, so I added an assumption. If you're not sure about leading +, the solution with the external TRIM is the only choice

Comment: @MT0 how can I incorporate this into your answer given in the question linked so everything can be performed serially?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something on the lines of:

```
 Select substr('1+2+3+', 0, length('1+2+3+')-1) from dual ;
 Select replace('1++2', '++', '+') from dual;
```

I'm assuming you have the output already present in a variable you can play with.

EDIT:
Here's a function that can solve the problem (You can call this function in your select clauses thereby solving the problem):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function ReplaceChars
    ( name_in IN varchar2 )
    RETURN varchar2
IS
    changed_string varchar2(20) ;
BEGIN

    changed_string:=replace(name_in, '++', '+') ;

    CASE WHEN substr(changed_string, -1) in ('+')
        then
            changed_string:=substr(changed_string,0, length(changed_string) - 1) ;
        else changed_string:=changed_string ;
    end CASE ;

    RETURN changed_string;
END;
```

Comment: this is hard-coding values, is it possible to add in both column names?

Comment: how do I modify this for both my columns? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: @Laura Select ReplaceChars(col1), ReplaceChars(col2) from <table> ;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE (column_name, '\+{2,}', '+'), '+'),'+')
```

Eg:

```
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE ('+A+++B+C+++D++', '\+{2,}', '+'), '+'),'+') VALUE
  FROM DUAL;
```

returns output: `A+B+C+D`

Comment: how can I use this but update at the same time.?

So read the two columns and update both columns to reflect changes

Comment: @Laura Yes. you need to pass both the Name and Value columns in the above function. The output of which can be used for further processing

Answer (score -1):

if youre working with ssms, GIVE IT A GO:::

```
UPDATE tablename
SET colname= 
CASE colname WHEN LIKE '%++%' THEN
    WHILE colname LIKE '%++%'
        (REPLACE(colname,++,+))
    END LOOP

WHEN LIKE '%+' THEN
    SUBSTR(colname, 1, LENGTH(colname)-1)

WHEN LIKE '+%' THEN
    SUBSTR(colname, 2, LENGTH(colname))

ELSE
   colname
END
```

Comment: Oracle(NOT SQL SERVER) doesn't support `LEFT()` and `LEN()` functions.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov, I guess "LTRIM" AND 'RTRIM' can vbe used equivalently to replace 'LEFT' AND 'RIGHT' functions respectvely. also 'LENGTH'  can be used instead of 'LEN'
please refer that.

Comment: where the set statement is, is this only doing one column? Can I seperate it by , so it performs this on 2 columns?

Comment: @Laura, you should use "SET" for each time you want update values to the column. be it one column or more.

Comment: this construct doesn't work with oracle.. I get an error of "SQL command not ended properly"

Comment: Seems I missed END LOOP for WHILE statement there, @Laura. Sorry for that. You can now check it