# Replace string where ++ exists SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This relates to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365517/remove-extra-from-text-sql/44366707?noredirect=1#comment75737873_44366707)

What I now want to do is in my value column, if there are any instance of ++ replace this with 999.

So for e.g. if i have `1+2++3`this should be updated to `1+2+999+3`

How do i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: As you say, this is related to your previous question, but you never posted an attempt to write some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can use `REPLACE`. Have you tried using that ?

Comment: @Aleksej
I have tried `SELECT REPLACE (value, '++', '999') 
FROM my_table  ;
but this does not keep the + in the replace it just returns 19993

Comment: If you replace '++' with '999' then of course the '++' are gone. You want to replace with '+999+'.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks for pointing that out, does as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value ) AS
  SELECT NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1+2'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1++2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '+1'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1+'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1+2++3' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TRIM( BOTH '+' FROM REPLACE( '+' || value || '+', '++', '+999+' ) )
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE
---------
999
1
1+2
1+999+2
999+1
1+999
1+2+999+3
```

If you can have more than one missing element to replace in a row then you need a more complicated solution:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value ) AS
  SELECT NULL      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1+2'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1++2'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '+1'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1+'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1+2++3'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1+2+++3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '+'       FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ( SELECT LISTAGG(
                  COALESCE(
                    REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '(.*?)(\+|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ),
                    '999'
                  ),
                  '+'
                ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY LEVEL )
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.value, '\+' ) + 1
       ) AS value
FROM   your_table t
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE
-------------
999
1
1+2
1+999+2
999+1
1+999
1+2+999+3
1+2+999+999+3
999+999
```

Comment: this takes into consideration things I didnt think about and only noticing now.
Thank you

Comment: great.. will need to take time out to understand this. Quick question how comes if I just have a + why does it update to '999+999' ?

Comment: @Laura `1+2` has two elements - the first (`1`) before the `+` and the second (`2`) after. Similarly `+` has two elements - the first (`NULL` - an empty string) before and the second (`NULL` - another empty string) after.

Comment: @Laura Simplified it to remove the table collection expression (since it was only ever going to return a single row from the `LISTAGG`)

Comment: Thank you very much, Makes perfect sense